# jQuery Accordion Menu and Checkbox Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

So I have a simple jQuery accordion style menu with check boxes in the header part of the menu.  This is to toggle a set of pins on a map depending on that category.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="mapMenu">
<ul id="accordion">
<li><div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="greenCheck" name="pinSet" value="Green"  class="pinToggles" onclick="pinSetCheck(greenSet)">Attractions
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Outdoor Waterparks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Indoor Waterparks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Go-kart Track</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="redCheck" name="pinSet" value="Red" class="pinToggles" onclick="pinSetCheck(redSet)">Dining & Shopping
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurant 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurant 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Restaurant 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="purpleCheck" name="pinSet" value="Purple"  class="pinToggles" onclick="pinSetCheck(purpleSet)">Groups & Meetings
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Conference Room 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Conference Room 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Conference Room 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="orangeCheck" name="pinSet" value="Orange"  class="pinToggles" onclick="pinSetCheck(orangeSet)">Golf
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Golf Course 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Golf Course 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Golf Course 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="darkBlueCheck" name="pinSet" value="Dark Blue"  class="pinToggles" onclick="pinSetCheck(darkBlueSet)">Spa</div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Spa 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spa 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spa 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$("#accordion li div").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBaKp/

If you check the box it activates the accordion for that category.  I do not want this.  I want it to stay unless they click on the rest of the that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this:

```
$(".pinToggles").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBaKp/1/

---

[`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) prevents a click event (or other event, such as `mouseover`) from bubbling up to the parents, causing their events to fire.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks!  It is crazy learning jQuery and seeing all the things it can do.

Comment: Javascript can do the same.

Comment: @KarolHernik Right, jQuery isn't necessary, this could be done just as easily in vanilla JS. The selector makes our code more maintainable though.